# DataTables Display Issue - Unformatted Table Blip

Tags: jquery, html, datatable

I'm just doing a simple DataTable display but I've noticed that when the page loads the unstyled HTML data table appears prior to the styled DataTable appearing. Can someone point out why that might be happening? Does the order of the script and link declarations make a difference?

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Demo DataTable Display</title>

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">

        <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>      

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css">

        <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>

        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $('#example').DataTable();
            });
        </script>


    </head>
    <body>
        <table id="example" class="display">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Column 1</th>
                    <th>Column 2</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>Row 1 Data 1</td>
                    <td>Row 1 Data 2</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Row 2 Data 1</td>
                    <td>Row 2 Data 2</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try to add your scripts at the bottom of your page

Comment: I tried moving the scripts above the </body> tag but I'm still getting the glitch.

Answer (score 0):

maybe try to populate your datatables via Ajax with the deferRender option enabled. I use this and never had rendering problems since data are loaded asynchroneously. Below is an exemple of implementation :

```
// HTML
<table id="example">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Col 1</th>
            <th>Col 2</th>
            <th>Col 3</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th>Col 1</th>
            <th>Col 2</th>
            <th>Col 3</th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>


// DATATABLE AJAX SCRIPT
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    ajax: {
        url: 'your-datatable-populate-script',
        type: 'POST',
        data: function(d) {

        },
    },
    deferRender: true,
    pageLength: 10,

    initComplete: function(settings, json) {

    },
});

// PHP POPULATE SCRIPT
<?php
    $json[] = array(
        'Data 1',
        'Data 2',
        'Data 3',
    );

    $response = array();
    $response['data'] = $json;
    $response['success'] = TRUE;

    echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

References : https://datatables.net/manual/ajax

Examples :

- https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/simple.html
- https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/objects.html

DeferRender :

By default, when DataTables loads data from an Ajax or Javascript data source (ajax and data respectively) it will create all HTML elements needed up-front. When working with large data sets, this operation can take a not-insignificant amount of time, particularly in older browsers such as IE6-8. This option allows DataTables to create the nodes (rows and cells in the table body) only when they are needed for a draw.

As an example to help illustrate this, if you load a data set with 10,000 rows, but a paging display length of only 10 records, rather than create all 10,000 rows, when deferred rendering is enabled, DataTables will create only 10. When the end user then sorts, pages or filters the data the rows needed for the next display will be created automatically. This effectively spreads the load of creating the rows across the life time of the page.